# Edit a dataframe 'inplace' in a function, or return the edited dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently working on a function to update a dataframe.

There are two ways I can do this.

**Example 1**: Edit in place.

Create the dataframe

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'name':['jim','john','mary','michael'],
                    'age':[12,46,44,32]})

      name  age
0      jim   12
1     john   46
2     mary   44
3  michael   32
```

And we will do the following edits:

1. If the name begins with `j`, add `'smith'` to the name.
2. If the age is greater than 40, multiply it by 2.

```
def modify(df):

    for i in range(len(df)):

        # if age is >40
        if df.loc[i,'age'] > 40:

            # multiply it by 2
            df.loc[i,'age'] = df.loc[i,'age']*2

        # get the name
        name = df.loc[i,'name']

        # if it starts with 'j'
        if name[0]=='j':

            # add 'smith' to the name
            name = name+' '+'smith'

        # insert into cell    
        df.loc[i,'name'] = name
```

Works fine. I haven't returned anything from the function and the dataframe has been edited:

```
modify(mydf)

print(mydf)

         name  age
0   jim smith   12
1  john smith   92
2        mary   88
3     michael   32
```

**Example 2** I can also do this by returning the dataframe, as seen below. My question is: what's the difference? Is one method preferred over the other?

```
def modify(df):

    for i in range(len(df)):

        if df.loc[i,'age'] > 40:

            df.loc[i,'age'] = df.loc[i,'age']*2

        name = df.loc[i,'name']

        if name[0]=='j':

            name = name+' '+'smith'

        df.loc[i,'name'] = name

    return df
```

Running the function:

```
mydf = modify(mydf)

print(mydf)

         name  age
0   jim smith   12
1  john smith   92
2        mary   88
3     michael   32
```

Both work fine. Is it better to edit in place or return the `dataframe`?

**Note**: I can't do vectorization as I am using api's in the actual function I am working on. This is just a toy example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would always choose to return the DataFrame. If you plan to assign the output to another variable (`df1 = my_func(df)`) call the function with `df.copy()` or ensure you `.copy()` right at the top of your function to never accidentally modify your input.

`DataFrames` are mutable, so like lists they can be modified within functions without returning them. However, this can lead to a lot of confusion when you use a `pandas` function that returns a new object, instead of modifying the original.

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['jim', 'jim'],
                     'age': [12, 46]})

def modify(df):
    df.loc[df.name.eq('jim'), 'age'] = 1000

print(mydf)
#  name  age
#0  jim   12
#1  jim   46

modify(mydf)
print(mydf)
#  name   age
#0  jim  1000
#1  jim  1000
```

---

Okay great, that changed. But what about if we continue with:

```
def modify2(df):
    df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
    df['age'] = df['age'] + 1

    df = pd.concat([df]*4)
    df['age'] = df['age'] + 17

modify2(mydf)
print(mydf)
#  name   age
#0  jim  1001
```

So that's not great. Basically the function only succeeded in modifying `df` up until some part of our function returned a new object and not a reference to the original. This is very problematic, and requires every operation to operate inplace otherwise it's going to fail.

Comment: Good explanation, thanks. What if I do want to modify the original dataframe and not `.copy()` it? For example, in my function (not the one here) there is an api call to verify an email address. I will add an extra column `df['email_verification'] = 'valid'` if it's a valid email. So I send the dataframe with customer data and emails into the function, and new data is appended. Should I still use `.copy()`? What if the dataframe has 1 million rows? I will be creating an huge extra copy of the data.

Comment: If the result is to modify the original (`df = my_func(df)`) then there isn't so much a need to add a `.copy()` as the intent is to modify the original, so whether it gets accidentally modified before the return isn't so important. Though you might get some `SetWithCopy` warnings occasionally. But yes, I would  add a `return df` at the end of the function and then `df = my_func(df)`

Answer (score 1):

We usually do `np.where` which will speed up the whole process

```
df['name']=np.where(df.name.str[0]=='j',df.name+'smith',df.name)
df['age']=np.where(df.age>40,df.age*2,df.age)
df
Out[90]: 
        name  age
0   jimsmith   12
1  johnsmith   92
2       mary   88
3    michael   32
```

Comment: Thanks but the function I'm working on is much more complex, there are calls to api's depending on conditions etc . `np.where` will be too fast for the api. I just want to know which of the above methods is more preferred

Comment: @SCool I will recommend 2nd, also , you can change the .loc to .at to speed it up

Comment: Thanks @WeNYoBen I didn't know about `.at`.