# Python parameter-passing and value-returning confusion

Tags: python, pandas, parameters, return-value

I broke a long section of data-processing code into smaller functions for clarity. The last step is to normalize the values in the data frame; however, I want to keep the pre-normalized data in a separate variable so it can be compared to the post-normalized data in a report. The problem is, the pre- and post-normalization data keep ending up the same (same data *and* same `id()` values). I finally got it to work by adding a call to `.copy()` when I pass it in to `normalize()`, but I would like to understand more about Python's parameter-passing and value-returning behavior and why it wasn't working before.

**Bad code (pre_df and post_df are equal):**

```
def process_data(report_fields):                                                   
    pre_df = fetch_raw_data(report_fields)                                         
    pre_df = prepare_data(pre_df, report_fields)                                   
    pre_df = impute(pre_df, report_fields)                                         
    post_df = normalize(pre_df, report_fields)                              
                                                                               
    return pre_df, post_df
```

**Good code (pre_df and post_df are different):**

```
def process_data(report_fields):                                                   
    pre_df = fetch_raw_data(report_fields)                                         
    pre_df = prepare_data(pre_df, report_fields)                                   
    pre_df = impute(pre_df, report_fields)                                         
    post_df = normalize(pre_df.copy(), report_fields)
```

The only difference is in the 5th line, where I make a copy of the variable being passed in.

Comment: DataFrames **are mutable** and so, like lists, if the function modifies the object the references outside of the function reflect those changes. This seems hit or miss because many times `pandas` functions return a new object, so often potentially problematic code missing an explicit copy sneaks by without issue (or the function meant to modify the original so it's a moot point). Using `.copy` guarantees a new object is created to ensure that the function cannot mistakenly modify the original object

Comment: Here's a somewhat related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57999489/edit-a-dataframe-inplace-in-a-function-or-return-the-edited-dataframe/57999678#57999678

Comment: I read the related question, and that behavior on the part of pandas does seem confusing & error-prone. So the rule of thumb is a) ```copy()``` the DataFrame being passed into a function and b) ```return``` the DataFrame from the function (rather than modifying in place).

Comment: Right, it's one of the gotchas of python with mutable objects. Normally it's not a big issue because many operations follow something like `df = my_modify_func(df)` so you pass `df` but mean to modify it anyway so who cares if the function modifies it! On the other hand `df = my_modify_func(df, other_arg=df1)` now has the potential to modify `df1`, which you probably don't want to do so it would be safest to do `df = my_modify_func(df, other_arg=df1.copy())`. But copying can be slow for super big DataFrames so it can be wasteful if you're sure `df1` doesn't get modified by the function.